# Can I connect to Google Cloud VM's through Chrome OS?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-os

In [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#standardssh) I found this example:

`ssh -i KEY_FILE -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@IP_ADDRESS`

But in Chrome OS in console I can't run `ssh-keygen` - therefore I not have `KEY_FILE`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily connect to your Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance using either SSH or RDP (remote desktop protocol) through the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) by selecting **your project** **->** **Compute** **on the left panel** **->** **Compute Engine** **->** **VM Instances** **->** and clicking the **SSH or RDP button** next to your Compute Engine VM instance. RDP connections will use the provided Chrome extension to connect and [SSH will be opened in a new tab](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser).